# PHP remote connection to MSSQL failing

Tags: php, sql-server-2005

I have my first PHP project and I can connect to a SQL server database on my local SQL Server express but when I attempt to connect to a remote connection it fails.  This is the connection that works locally;

$serverName = "IT90334\SQLEXPRESS, 1433";

But I have tried the following connections;

```
$serverName = "servername\MSSQLInstancename, 40009";
$serverName = ""server.I.P.Address\MSSQLInstancename, 40009";
$serverName = "//server.I.P.Address\MSSQLInstancename, 40009";
$serverName = "//server.I.P.Address\MSSQLInstancename";
$serverName = "server.I.P.Address"
$serverName = "server.I.P.Address:40009"
```

They output an error to the browser that initially states one of the following;

Provider: No such host is known
Error Locating Server/Instance Specified and
Timing out
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Then the next part of the error states;

A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections

I can telnet to the server using this command

```
C:\telnet servername 40009
```

But it still won't connect.  What am I missing here?  Below is a section of the PHP and obviosuly I am looking for the "Connection established" to be shown in the browser

```
$serverName = "servername\MSSQLInstancename, 40009";

$connectionInfo = array('Database' => 'AuditDEV');
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection Established.<br />";
} else {
   echo "Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL.<br />";
   die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
```

}

Comment: If you have the IP address, can you ping it? If so an you get a repsonse, try adding that name and IP to the hosts file. Also [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2340/resolving-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-errors/) is some addititonal info on things to try/check.

Comment: @DDurham Thanks.  Yes I checked I could ping it.  I wil add the details to my local hosts file and try it

Comment: @DDurham Thanks.  Okay I have tried the hosts file amendment and used $serverName = "servername\MSSQLInstancename, 40009";  The outcome is the error "TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Comment: well the root issue is in TCP resolution. Can you ping the machine by name and if so is it an IP v4 address (if it's v6 you may need to disable that). Also make sure the browser service is running on the system. Otheriwise it may be a port issue and [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2007/07/19/tcp-provider-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it/) has some things to check for that

Comment: @DDurham Thanks again for response.  Yes I can ping the server using the server name and the IP address is returned.  I have also checked the SQL Server Browser service is running

Comment: did you try the things in the link for checking the port? Or maybe set things up to use a different port? If the IP is correct and v4, and the browser service is running, and no firewall or anything else is blocking the IP/PORT. it would seem the port is likely the culprit...

Comment: @DDurham Thanks again.  Yes I checked many of the things in the link URL you provided.  The SQL Server Browser service is running, the database instance is listening and on a port 40009 (this port is not my choosing it is our server teams and I will not be able to change the port number).  I can telnet to the IP address and port number so no firewall issues

Comment: Sorry... but stumped then... everything seems to be in place and correct.

Comment: @DDurham Yes.  Me to.  I am going to try the PDO option